# Sorting an array

Tags: java, array, sorting

I wrote this program for sorting an array of type `String` alphabetical without using `compareTo()` method so I am saying that if you can find errors in my program please tell me I will try to fix it.

```
class some{
 public static void main(String[] args)  {
  String array[]={"names here"};
  System.out.print("before:");
 for (int    i=0 ;i<array.length;i++ ) 
    System.out.print(array[i]+" ");

 array  = SortA(array);
      System.out.println();
           System.out.print("after:");
     for (int    i=0 ;i<array.length;i++ ) 
      System.out.print(array[i]+" ");


}//end of main method

    public static int getSmallestRange(String[] array){
        int range = array[0].length()-1;
        for (int i =0;i<array.length ;i++ ) {

            if(range>array[i].length()-1){
                range = array[i].length()-1;

            }

        }
        return range ;
}
  public static String[] SortA(String [] array){
         String tmp="";
  int index = 0 ;
  for (int i =0;i<array.length ;i++ ) 
        for (int j = i+1;j<array.length ;j++ ) {
              if(array[i].charAt(index)>array[j].charAt(index)){
                          tmp = array[i];
                          array[i] = array[j];
                          array[j] = tmp ;
              }//end of if
        }//end of loop
        index++;

        for (int x =0;x<array.length-1 ;x++ ){
              for (int y =x+1;y<array.length ;y++ ) {


              if(array[x].charAt(0)==array[y].charAt(0)){

                    if(array[x].charAt(index)>array[y].charAt(index)){
                          tmp = array[x];
                          array[x] = array[y];
                          array[y] = tmp ;

                    }

                    else if(array[x].charAt(index)==array[y].charAt(index)){
                    if(index<getSmallestRange(array))
                          index++;
                    }

              }//end of if
        }//end of loop
  }

  return array;
 }//end of method
}
```

Comment: Currently it's incorrect, given an initial array of `{"dds", "dda"}`, it fails to sort them properly.

Comment: First off, you have to properly format your code. The indentation is off and very confusing.

Comment: @MichaelZedeler: I think checking and correcting usage of whitespace is appropriate for a code review. I mean that no properly formatted code in here is not a "problem", as we are here to point these things out. Just pointing that out because you said "first off, you have to..." which makes it sound like it is a criteria (which I disagree with).

Comment: In this context, I mean that formatting is first priority over everything else. Learning to program requires that you read and re-read your own code over and over again, so not formatting it right is really getting in the way of ever getting better.

Comment: @MichaelZedeler: I completely agree with that!

Answer (score 1):

First off, your use of whitespace is a mess, fix it. Press "Format Code" in your favorite IDE or do it manually.

---

```
class some{
```

- [The Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html) say that class names should be UpperCamelCase.
- Use a visibility modificator for clearness (`private`, `public`).

---

```
String array[]={"names here"};
```

Use descriptive variable names, like `sourceArray` or `unsortedArray`.

---

```
for (int    i=0 ;i<array.length;i++ )
```

- Use appropriate variable names. This is a little bit unpopular with most people, but I prefer to use descriptive names even for such simple loops (`int idx`).
- As said before, your use pf whitespace is very confusing:

  ```
  for (int idx = 0; idx < array.length; idx++) {
  ```
- Use appropriate loops, in this case a `for-each` loop:

  ```
  for (String item : array) {
  ```

---

```
String tmp="";
int index = 0 ;
```

Declaring variables once and reusing them through out whole function, especially larger functions, is bad. Declare variables where you need them and name them appropriately, like this:

```
String swapTemp = array[i];
array[i] = array[j];
array[j] = swapTemp;
```

---

```
       }//end of if
 }//end of loop
```

If code is correctly formatted, short and precise (only do one function per function), such comments are absolutely unnecessary.

---

Consider [using the Java Documentation feature](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html).